# Airflow scheduler still running on days it shouldn't

Tags: airflow

I've seen a couple of responses to similar questions but I can seem to wrap my head around this one. We have a process that we want to run only on set days so Tues-Sat at 8am.

```
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 27),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
}
   
with DAG(
        dag_id='dag_name',
        schedule_interval='0 8 * * Tue-Sat',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args
) as dag:
```

However the DAG is still running everyday. Have I missed something?

Comment: That is indeed odd. I put your Cron string into a test DAG and it should work as you intend. Some questions that might help narrow down the problem: what Airflow version are you on? Does the issue persist when using `0 8 * * 2-6` as the schedule? Can you share the `logical_date` and Data Interval for the run that happened unexpectedly? (and just to double check, is there any external trigger like a TriggerDagRunOperator aimed at this DAG?)

Comment: using version 2.2.2 and there is no external trigger. logical date (im assuming this is execution date ) is 2023-04-2-04 08:00:00 and data interval start 2023-02-04 08:00:00 and end 2023-02-05 00:00:00. I'll give it a go with the update cron schedule